# How do I select from a non-aliased inline function column header in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm writing a Java program that grabs a (SQL Query) String from an Oracle database, executes that string against the same database, and then executes another query to get the column mapping needed in order to validate that data against an external result.

I would like to do this all in one SQL call, so that I can cleanly return a Java ResultSet object using PreparedStatement.executeQuery

The way I've solved this thus far is to first reference the column mapping query, and then write a wrapper that grabs necessary columns from the stored query. For example, a resultant SQL query may look like:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM(
    select col1, col2, col3 from table a

)
```

In the above example, col3 is discarded without me ever having to edit the stored SQL query.

This has worked until I have reached the following edge case - the SQL my code produces is:

```
SELECT NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.FIRSTRESTRICT,0), NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.LASTRESTRICT,0) FROM(
    select a, NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.FIRSTRESTRICT,0), NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.LASTRESTRICT,0) 
    from (sometable and wheres)
)
```

As best as I can tell, there does not seem to be a way I could refer to that functional call without it being aliased within the original query, right? I can't refer to the column number without writing to a temporary table (and I don't have write permissions with this app), and I can't refer to it directly by its functional signature.

Is there some easy way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WITH` clause (11.2+):

```
WITH X (C1, C2, C3) AS (
    select a, NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.FIRSTRESTRICT,0), NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.LASTRESTRICT,0) 
    from (sometable and wheres)
)
SELECT C2, C3
FROM X
```

**UPDATE**

If the `SELECT` statement already starts with a `WITH` clause, you can't do that, but you can rearranging the statement is "fairly" simple, i.e. find the actual `SELECT` statement and move it into a new `WITH` element.

Example:

```
-- Before
WITH A AS (
    SELECT ... FROM tableA ...
), B AS (
    SELECT ... FROM tableB ...
)
SELECT ... FROM A, B, tableC ...

-- After
WITH A AS (
    SELECT ... FROM tableA ...
), B AS (
    SELECT ... FROM tableB ...
), X (C1, C2, C3) AS (
    SELECT ... FROM A, B, tableC ...
)
SELECT C2, C3
FROM X
```

Comment: I didn't specify before - but there's a nested WITH. Tragically didn't think it was relevant before, until I tried this answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name According to the [Oracle 11.1 manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2161315), the *subquery_factoring_clause* doesn't allow specifying new column aliases, which is the feature used here, so for this answer to work, you need 11.2 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enclose the column expression in double quotes in the outer query, converting to uppercase first. This works:

```
select "LOWER(DUMMY)" 
from 
( 
  select lower(dummy) from dual 
)

LOWER(DUMMY)
------------
x
```

So in theory you can force your statement to:

```
SELECT "NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.FIRSTRESTRICT,0)", "NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.LASTRESTRICT,0)" FROM(
    select a, NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.FIRSTRESTRICT,0), NVL(RESTRICTTABLE.LASTRESTRICT,0) 
    from (sometable and wheres)
)
```

However, you're restricted by the maximum length of an identifier, which is only 30 bytes up to 12cR1 and increases to 128 bytes from 12cR2. Truncating the identifier *might* work, but it's feasible you'd then get clashes.

You might be better off getting the [result set metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) for your original inner query and deciding which columns to use from that. It depends a bit on how your column mapping works, and what that query actually returns.

(Or, of course, you could insist that the stored queries alias all their column expressions so you can just refer to those - but it sounds like that isn't an option.)

Comment: This is what I ended up using 

The database is set up such that the columns used in the outer select are stored and retrieved with a seperate query - i.e, get c1, c3, c4 from the "inner" select. So, as I was setting up my "outer" query I first checked to see if I needed to alias the column (i.e, if it is functional or over 30 characters) and then threw it in double quotes.

Thanks for your help!